# jQuery function after an AJAX Content load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

When I reload the page with AJAX from my PHP, I can't seem to get my jQuery function that affects each item in the `enlarge` class.
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Gallery</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/gallery.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" 
                src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src="js/enlarge.js"></script>
        <script>
            function showImage(str) {
                if (str.length == 0) {
                    document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = "";
                    return;
                } else {
                    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                            document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;                           
                        }
                    }
                    xmlhttp.open("GET", "info.php?q=" + str, true);
                    xmlhttp.send();
                }

            }
        </script>   
    </head>
    <body>  
            <div id="side-nav">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <select id="categories" onchange="showImage(this.value)">
                        <option value="All_Cat">All</option>
                        <option value="Inks">Inks</option>
</select>
</div> 
            <!-- IMAGE CONTAINER --> 
            <div id="image"></div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

PhP:

```
<?php
$folder = "";
$array = array();

// get the q parameter from URL
$q = $_REQUEST["q"];

$display_image = "";

//Switch Statement to evaluate $q
switch ($q) {
    case "All_Cat":
        $folder = './img_gallery/*';
        foreach (glob($folder . '*.*') as $filename) {
        $array[] = $filename;
    }
    foreach ($array as $image) {
        if ($array === "") {
            $display_image = $image;
        } else {
            $display_image .= " <img height=\"100\" width=\"100\" class=\"enlarge\" src='$image'/>";
        }
    }
    break;
   default:
        echo "No images";
}

// Output "no suggestion" if no hint was found or output correct values 
echo $display_image === "" ? "No images" : $display_image;
```

JavaScript/JQUERY:

```
jQuery.noConflict()

jQuery.imageEnlarge = {
    dsettings: {
        enlargeby: 4.3, //default increase factor of enlarged image
        duration: 500, //default duration of animation, in millisec
        imgopacity: 0.2 //opacify of original image when enlarged image overlays it
    },
    zIndexcounter: 100,
    refreshoffsets: function ($window, $target, warpshell) {
        var $offsets = $target.offset()
        var winattrs = {x: $window.scrollLeft(), y: $window.scrollTop(), w: $window.width(), h: $window.height()}
        warpshell.attrs.x = $offsets.left //update x position of original image relative to page
        warpshell.attrs.y = $offsets.top
        warpshell.newattrs.x = winattrs.x + winattrs.w / 2 - warpshell.newattrs.w / 2
        warpshell.newattrs.y = winattrs.y + winattrs.h / 2 - warpshell.newattrs.h / 2
        if (warpshell.newattrs.x < winattrs.x + 5) { //no space to the left?
            warpshell.newattrs.x = winattrs.x + 5
        }
        else if (warpshell.newattrs.x + warpshell.newattrs.w > winattrs.x + winattrs.w) {//no space to the right?
            warpshell.newattrs.x = winattrs.x + 5
        }
        if (warpshell.newattrs.y < winattrs.y + 5) { //no space at the top?
            warpshell.newattrs.y = winattrs.y + 5
        }
    },
    enlarge: function ($, $target, options) {
        var setting = {} //create blank object to store combined settings
        var setting = jQuery.extend(setting, this.dsettings, options)
        var attrs = (options.thumbdimensions) ? {w: options.thumbdimensions[0], h: options.thumbdimensions[1]} : {w: $target.outerWidth(), h: $target.outerHeight()}
        var newattrs = {}
        newattrs.w = (setting.enlargeto) ? setting.enlargeto : Math.round(attrs.w * setting.enlargeby)
        newattrs.h = (setting.enlargeto) ? Math.round(attrs.h * newattrs.w / attrs.w) : Math.round(attrs.h * setting.enlargeby)
        $target.css('cursor', jQuery.imageEnlarge.cursorcss)
        if ($target.data('imgshell')) {
            $target.data('imgshell').$clone.remove()
            $target.css({opacity: 1}).unbind('click.enlarge')
        }
        var $clone = $target.clone().css({position: 'absolute', left: 0, top: 0, visibility: 'hidden', border: '1px solid gray', cursor: 'pointer'}).appendTo(document.body)
        $clone.data('$relatedtarget', $target) //save $target image this enlarged image is associated with
        $target.data('imgshell', {$clone: $clone, attrs: attrs, newattrs: newattrs})
        $target.bind('click.enlarge', function (e) { //action when original image is clicked on
            var $this = $(this).css({opacity: setting.imgopacity})
            var imageinfo = $this.data('imgshell')
            jQuery.imageEnlarge.refreshoffsets($(window), $this, imageinfo) //refresh offset positions of original and warped images
            var $clone = imageinfo.$clone
            $clone.stop().css({zIndex: ++jQuery.imageEnlarge.zIndexcounter, left: imageinfo.attrs.x, top: imageinfo.attrs.y, width: imageinfo.attrs.w, height: imageinfo.attrs.h, opacity: 0, visibility: 'visible', display: 'block'})
                    .animate({opacity: 1, left: imageinfo.newattrs.x, top: imageinfo.newattrs.y, width: imageinfo.newattrs.w, height: imageinfo.newattrs.h}, setting.duration,
                            function () { //callback function after warping is complete
                                //none added        
                            }) //end animate
        }) //end click
        $clone.click(function (e) { //action when enlarged image is clicked on
            var $this = $(this)
            var imageinfo = $this.data('$relatedtarget').data('imgshell')
            jQuery.imageEnlarge.refreshoffsets($(window), $this.data('$relatedtarget'), imageinfo) //refresh offset positions of original and warped images
            $this.stop().animate({opacity: 0, left: imageinfo.attrs.x, top: imageinfo.attrs.y, width: imageinfo.attrs.w, height: imageinfo.attrs.h}, setting.duration,
                    function () {
                        $this.hide()
                        $this.data('$relatedtarget').css({opacity: 1}) //reveal original image
                    }) //end animate
        }) //end click
    }
};

jQuery.fn.imageEnlarge = function (options) {
    var $ = jQuery
    return this.each(function () { //return jQuery obj
        var $imgref = $(this)
        if (this.tagName != "IMG")
            return true //skip to next matched element
        if (parseInt($imgref.css('width')) > 0 && parseInt($imgref.css('height')) > 0 || options.thumbdimensions) { //if image has explicit width/height attrs defined
            jQuery.imageEnlarge.enlarge($, $imgref, options)
        }
        else if (this.complete) { //account for IE not firing image.onload
            jQuery.imageEnlarge.enlarge($, $imgref, options)
        }
        else {
            $(this).bind('load', function () {
                jQuery.imageEnlarge.enlarge($, $imgref, options)
            })
        }
    })
};

jQuery.fn.applyMagnifier = function (options) { //dynamic version of imageEnlarge() to apply enlarge effect to an image dynamically
    var $ = jQuery
    return this.each(function () { //return jQuery obj
        var $imgref = $(this)
        if (this.tagName != "IMG")
            return true //skip to next matched element

    })

};


//** The following applies the enlarge effect to images with class="enlarge" and optional "data-enlargeby" and "data-enlargeduration" attrs
//** It also looks for links with attr rel="enlarge[targetimageid]" and makes them togglers for that image


jQuery("document").ready(function ($) {
    var $targets = $('.enlarge')
    $targets.each(function (i) {
        var $target = $(this)
        var options = {}
        if ($target.attr('data-enlargeto'))
            options.enlargeto = parseFloat($target.attr('data-enlargeto'))
        if ($target.attr('data-enlargeby'))
            options.enlargeby = parseFloat($target.attr('data-enlargeby'))
        if ($target.attr('data-enlargeduration'))
            options.duration = parseInt($target.attr('data-enlargeduration'))
        $target.imageEnlarge(options)
    })
    var $triggers = $('a[rel^="enlarge["]')
    $triggers.each(function (i) {
        var $trigger = $(this)
        var targetid = $trigger.attr('rel').match(/\[.+\]/)[0].replace(/[\[\]']/g, '') //parse 'id' from rel='enlarge[id]'
        $trigger.data('enlargeimageid', targetid)
        $trigger.click(function (e) {
            $('#' + $(this).data('enlargeimageid')).trigger('click.enlarge')
            e.preventDefault()
        })
    })
})
```

The AJAX call function is within the HTML code that loads the images to the "image" container. I have the PHP respond with `"class="enlarge"` within the img item, but the query doesn't kick off. I have found out that this is because the jQuery is loading when the site is initially launched and the bindings are lost when AJAX is called.
Can anyone assist me with fixing this so the `class="enlarge"` feature works again?

**EDITED CODE:**

```
function addBehaviour() {
    var $targets = $('.enlarge');
    $targets.each(function (i) {
        var $target = $(this);
        var options = {};
        if ($target.attr('data-enlargeto'))
            options.enlargeto = parseFloat($target.attr('data-enlargeto'));
        if ($target.attr('data-enlargeby'))
            options.enlargeby = parseFloat($target.attr('data-enlargeby'));
        if ($target.attr('data-enlargeduration'))
            options.duration = parseInt($target.attr('data-enlargeduration'));
        $target.imageEnlarge(options);
    });
    var $triggers = $('a[rel^="enlarge["]');
    $triggers.each(function (i) {
        var $trigger = $(this);
        var targetid = $trigger.attr('rel').match(/\[.+\]/)[0].replace(/[\[\]']/g, ''); //parse 'id' from rel='enlarge[id]'
        $trigger.data('enlargeimageid', targetid);
        $trigger.click(function (e) {
            $('#' + $(this).data('enlargeimageid')).trigger('click.enlarge');
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
}

jQuery("document").ready(function ($) {    
   addBehaviour();
});
```

AJAX:

```
<script>
            function showImage(str) {
                if (str.length == 0) {
                    document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = "";
                    return;
                } else {
                    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                            document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;   
                            addBehaviour();
                        }
                    }
                    xmlhttp.open("GET", "info.php?q=" + str, true);
                    xmlhttp.send();
                }
            }
        </script>
```

**Answer:**

Commented out `jQuery.noConflict();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest moving the application of behaviour to a seperate function, and using the `on()` and `off()` instead of `click()` like this:

```
function addBehaviour() {
        console.log( 'addBehaviour is called' );
/*       (... your other code...)
         off() removes the behaviour if present, on() adds it. 
         This way it does not get applied multiple times: */

        $trigger.off('click').on('click', function(e) {
            $('#' + $(this).data('enlargeimageid')).trigger('click.enlarge')
            e.preventDefault()
        });
```

Call the function 'addBehaviour' on document load:

`jQuery("document").ready(function($) {
            //....(your other on document ready code)...
            console.log( 'document ready' );
            addBehaviour();
    })`

And call 'addBehaviour'every time after the data arrived via your ajax call so it can re-apply the behaviour.

(Assuming this is the part where you load the stuff with ajax)

`xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
         document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
         // HERE: (after you have manipulated the dom)
         addBehaviour();

      }
   }`

Comment: Sorry, new to this AJAX and JQuery. Where would I put the 'addBehaviour' function in the ajax to call it every time?

Comment: I just updated my answer, please let me know if my assumption is right

Comment: Okay, that is exactly what I thought. Was making sure because it still doesn't seem to be calling or loading the function.

Comment: Also, I noticed when I move the code to the new function and calling it in the "document".ready(function). It doesn't work with a existing image that loads when the page loads.

Comment: Have you moved the other code to the addBehaviour() function as well?        var $targets = $('.enlarge')
    $targets.each(function (i) {
.... etcetera

Comment: Yes I moved all the code from document.ready to the new function addBehaviour. Then added the addBehaviour to the if statement in my Ajax call under the responsetext.  And added addBehaviour to my document.ready function in the jquery file. I'll post updated code once I get to my PC.

Comment: What browser do you use?

Comment: Tried in Google Chrome, Edge, and FireFox.

Comment: I added console.log() statements to the code in the document.ready handler and in the addbehaviour function, do you know how to see the output of console.log() ? In chrome - Open the developers console with ctrl+shift+i

Comment: I added that. Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function addBehaviour @ enlarge.js:104(anonymous function) @ enlarge.js:130(anonymous function) @ jquery.min.js:19o.extend.each @ jquery.min.js:12o.extend.ready @ jquery.min.js:19(anonymous function) @ jquery.min.js:19   I have never dealt with something like this. Trying to google it now.

Comment: Okay, so I found out that the "$" can't be used with jQuery.noConflict(); With not having that have, can there be any kind of negative feedback? Otherwise it works. And I can't thank you enough.

Comment: It means it cannot find the shortcut for jquery (the dollar sign $)

Comment: You can replace the '$' with 'jQuery' in the addBehaviour function

Comment: Also replace the  $trigger.click(function (e) { with the line I mentioned, otherwise the behaviour will be applied multiple times:  $trigger.off('click').on('click', function(e) {

Comment: Great, glad I could help! Please accept my answer and good luck with your project! Cheers

Comment: (If your site goes live, remove or comment the console.log statements, otherwise they will cause errors in some browsers)

Comment: Great will do. I also added that line you mentioned and it works as expected.

Comment: Happy to hear that! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are attaching events to the .enlarge class on the document ready event, but the content that is loaded with AJAX is loaded after that event, so you need to "rerun" the function of the document ready event.

you can do it by putting it in a separate function, and attaching the document ready event and ajax callback events to the same function.